# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided(deploying app to Heroku)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a simple html/css/js app to Heroku and I've set up my back-end with Node.js like this:

*(server.js)*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('dice-game'));

//routes
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index");
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("app running");
})
```

*(Procfile)*

```
web: npm server.js
```

*(package.json)*

```
{
  "name": "dice-game",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "js application",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.8.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/zay-asad/dice-game.git"
  },
  "author": "zayan asad",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zay-asad/dice-game/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/zay-asad/dice-game#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to run node locally with **"node server.js"** I get the following error message:

Error:

```
No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /Users/oas03/dice-game/server.js:10:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/oas03/dice-game/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Also, Heroku says my app has been deployed successfully but whenever I click "open application" from the UI I get this

[application_error_heroku_ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUFXN.png)

Anybody has this issue before? Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

So I've now set it up like this

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('dice-game'));

//routes
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { 
      root: path.join('dice-game', "dice-game") 
    });
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("app running");
})
```

But I am getting **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/oas03/dice-game/dice-game/dice-game/index.html'**

Any Idea? @Mark

Answer (score 0):

`res.render("index");` is used with a template engine, like handlebars or mustache. I assume you just want to send/serve the index.html file. Use `res.sendFile` instead

```js
var path = require("path");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('dice-game'));

//routes
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { 
      root: path.join(__dirname, "dice-game") 
    });
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("app running");
})
```

Comment: Hi, I've applied the suggested changes but getting a different error this time, can you look at my question again please? I've posted the new error above

Comment: Adjust/change the root path to your `index.html` file, i dont know your file structure, i tought your `index.html` is inside your `express.static(...)` serve static directory

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. Solution was to import each png image separately. It works!

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('dice-game'));

//routes
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { 
      root: __dirname
    });
})

//route
app.get("/style.css", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('style.css', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/dice-1.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-1.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/app.js", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('app.js', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/dice-2.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-2.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/dice-3.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-3.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/dice-4.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-4.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//rout
app.get("/dice-5.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-5.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

//route
app.get("/dice-6.png", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('dice-6.png', { 
    root: __dirname
  });
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("app running");
})
```